# GLSL: Float array in uniform buffer object

Tags: c++, arrays, glsl

I have an uniform buffer like this (GLSL/GPU):

```
layout(std140) uniform UConstantBufferPS1
{
    float m_LuminanceHistory[8];
};
```

I upload my data like this (C++/CPU):

```
SHistoryBuffer* pHistogramHistory = static_cast<SHistoryBuffer*>(Gfx::BufferManager::MapConstantBuffer(m_BufferSetPtr->GetBuffer(1)));

pHistogramHistory->m_LuminanceHistory[0] = 1.0f;
pHistogramHistory->m_LuminanceHistory[1] = 1.0f;
pHistogramHistory->m_LuminanceHistory[2] = 1.0f;
pHistogramHistory->m_LuminanceHistory[3] = 1.0f;
pHistogramHistory->m_LuminanceHistory[4] = 1.0f;
// ...

Gfx::BufferManager::UnmapConstantBuffer(m_BufferSetPtr->GetBuffer(1));
```

On the GLSL side everything is 0, except the first and second float value (m_LuminanceHistory[0]). It seems to be packed in a certain way!?

One bad solution is to define an array of float vectors (vec4) on CPU and GPU. Then I can iterate inside this array and read every x-value of the array. But then I have a big overhead.

Is there any good solution? Thx 4 ur help!

***EDIT:***

I used the following solution:

```
layout(std140) uniform UConstantBufferPS1
{
    vec4 m_LuminanceHistory[2];  
};

float History[8];

History[0] = m_LuminanceHistory[0].x;
History[1] = m_LuminanceHistory[0].y;
History[2] = m_LuminanceHistory[0].z;
History[3] = m_LuminanceHistory[0].w;
History[4] = m_LuminanceHistory[1].x;
History[5] = m_LuminanceHistory[1].y;
History[6] = m_LuminanceHistory[1].z;
History[7] = m_LuminanceHistory[1].w;
```

This solution works as expected but I don't know why I can't use float[8] directly.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you without seeing the code for `Gtx::BufferManager`.

Comment: It is nothing more then simply uploading data with "glBufferSubData".

Comment: @TobiasSchwandt It sounds like you might be forgetting to multiply the byte size by `sizeof(float)` when uploading the data.

Answer (score 0):

Without having much detail on your Gtx::BufferManager, I'm guessing the following possibilities that might help you to debug.

1. Try commenting out the layout(std140).
2. Double check that you have called glBindBufferBase() to bind the target of buffer object with the CORRECT binding point (By default it should start with 0, if you didn't specify it as you declare UConstantBufferPS1 in the shader).

Comment: Thx 4 ur response. I've tried commenting std140 but it doesn't work. The buffer is correctly binded.